# Firefox not working on Bonigarcia WebdriverManager other browsers works only firefox stopped working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Process unexpectedly closed with a status signal
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

I'm currently having a problem with the Firefox browser skipping my test won't just open and whenever I upgrade the Selenium web driver it works but won't allow implicit wait.

I'm not sure if this is a general problem. I have tried checking online to see what had happened but nothing pointed me in the right direction.

Is there something that needs to be done differently? I'm still using the Bonigarcia web manager.

Comment: "3.141.59" is a fairly old version of Selenium and may not be compatible with your version of Geckodriver.   You should probably update Selenium to the latest version.  Show code for your wait... they changed the constructors for waits to take a duration methinks.  (Used to be just an integer for seconds to timeout.)  New version ex: Duration.ofSeconds(your_timeout_in_seconds)... instead of just your_timeout_in_seconds.  Good news is the latest version has the webdrivermanager already built-in.